# Lock screen shows the wrong time (one hour later)

Tags: lock-screen

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 the lock screen is showing the wrong time, one hour later than the actual time. However, the time my system shows when it's not locked is correct,and it's set via NTP.

I'm using Gnome with gdm3 as the display manager.

My time zone is America/Chicago. I did a grep through `/etc` and I didn't find anything referencing another time zone.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You should be able to fix it from the Ubuntu settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set system time from the Terminal by running `sudo timedatectl set-time $TIME` You should replace $TIME with your time. If you are using a GUI, view [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/clock-set.html.en#:%7E:text=Click%20Date%20%26%20Time%20in%20the,adjust%20the%20time%20and%20date.) website to help.

Comment: I left out a key piece in my original question, which is that _outside the lock screen_ the clock it shows me is correct (and it uses NTP).